# Replace stored image in mysql by uploaded image

Tags: php, mysql

I am initially displaying an image through mysql.Now I want to replace that initial image by uploaded image.How can I do that?I am using this code to upload image on a webpage in PHP:

```
$UPLOADDIR = "upload/";

// if the form has been submitted then save and display the image(s)
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    // loop through the uploaded files

    foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value)
    {
        $image_tmp   = $value['tmp_name'];
        $image       = $value['name'];
        $image_file  = "{$UPLOADDIR}{$image}";

        // move the file to the permanent location

        if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,$image_file))
        {
            echo <<<HEREDOC
             <div style="float:left;margin-right:10px">
              <img src="{$image_file}" alt="file not found" /></br>
             </div>
           HEREDOC;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<h1>image file upload failed, image too big after compression</h1>";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    ?>

<form name='newad' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action=''>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='file' name='image'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name='Submit' type='submit' value='Upload image'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: you mean , u want to update the existing image ?? be more clear please !

Comment: @CodingAnt- yes i want to do that.

Comment: update the image info in db and delete/replace the old image

Comment: Where is your db structure or insert query to db

Comment: The code given below is the code that is displaying image stored in database:
// code to Connect to Database 
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{ 
 echo"<tr>";
 echo"<td>"; ?> <img src="<?php echo $row["images"]; ?>" height="100" width="100"> <?php echo "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>

Comment: db structure is: id INT and images VARCHAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply place the Update query When the Image has uploaded, and if you want to delete the existing then use unlink(PREVIOUS-FILE-NAME); this will delete the previous file.

```
    if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,$image_file))
    {
        EXECUTE UPDATE QUERY TO REPLACE EXISTING FILE
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h1>image file upload failed, image too big after compression</h1>";
    }
```

Comment: its not updating image in database and even not storing image in specified folder.

Comment: Then I shall need Database structure and Complete page code, since you are doing some logical error and it could not be rectify like this.

Comment: -this is the code that I am using to display image stored in database:                                                       <?php
// Connection to Database 
$result1= mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM $table" ) 
or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error()); 
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{ 
 echo"<tr>";
 echo"<td>"; ?> <img src="<?php echo $row["images"]; ?>" height="100" width="100"> <?php echo "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>

Comment: -My db structure is- ID int and images VARCHAR.The code that I hv mentioned above is the code of upload image.

Comment: its working.I have tried the code again and now its working.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nagin- I need a bit help of yours again. Actually its updating image in database but on webpage both images are displaying i.e. old image and uploaded image

Comment: Welcome. You might be updating image with the `id` attribute in the table, similarly if you fetch the result after your update query using `id` attribute in WHERE clause then this will replace your old image.

Comment: I am not updating image with the ID attribute,rather m using only images attribute to update the image.